# C# Async Socket Wrapper

Tags: c#, asynchronous, socket

I'd like to get a little feedback on this async socket wrapper. My goal is to merge socket Begin/End methods into a single async call. I also wanted to wrap exceptions so they are easier to handle in others areas of my program. Any red flags? Any potential problems? I know its not doing much but I want to get this right.

```
public class SimpleSocket
{
    private readonly Socket _socket;

    public SimpleSocket()
    {
        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    public SimpleSocket(Socket socket)
    {
        _socket = socket;
    }

    public void Bind(int port)
    {
        var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);

        try
        {
            _socket.Bind(endPoint);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ConnectionErrorException($"Failed to bind to {port}", e);
        }
    }

    public void Listen(int backlog)
    {
        try
        {
            _socket.Listen(backlog);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ConnectionErrorException($"Failed to listen with backlog of {backlog}", e);
        }
    }

    public async Task<SimpleSocket> AcceptAsync()
    {
        Socket socket;

        try
        {
            socket = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(_socket.BeginAccept, _socket.EndAccept, true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ConnectionErrorException("Failed to accept connection", e);
        }

        return new SimpleSocket(socket);
    }

    public async Task ConnectAsync(string host, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Factory.FromAsync(_socket.BeginConnect, _socket.EndConnect, host, port, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ConnectionErrorException($"Failed to connect to {host}:{port}", e);
        }
    }

    public async Task<int> ReceiveAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
    {
        int bytesReceived;

        try
        {
            bytesReceived = await Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(
                _socket.BeginReceive(buffer, offset, size, SocketFlags.None, null, null),
                _socket.EndReceive);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e is SocketException se && se.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.ConnectionReset)
            {
                throw new ConnectionClosedException("Connection reset");
            }

            throw new ConnectionErrorException("Failed to receieve message", e);
        }

        if (bytesReceived == 0)
        {
            throw new ConnectionClosedException("Connection closed");
        }

        return bytesReceived;
    }

    public async Task<int> SendAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
    {
        try
        {
            return await Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(
                _socket.BeginSend(buffer, offset, size, SocketFlags.None, null, null),
                _socket.EndSend);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ConnectionErrorException("Failed to send message", e);
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        _socket.Close();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Maybe I'll highlight some parts I'm concerned about. Am I doing the Task.Factory.FromAsync right? Especially for ReceiveAsync and SendAsync? I saw a strange example that looked like this:

```
  var revcLen = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                     (cb, s) => clientSocket.BeginReceive(prefix, 0, prefix.Length, SocketFlags.None, cb, s),
                     ias => clientSocket.EndReceive(ias),
                     null);
```

Why the extra lambda expression? It seems like they are just forcing the usage of one overload while another would be better suited.

Also, do you guys think I should just return zero bytes from ReceiveAsync instead of throwing ConnectionClosedException? Then I can just let the exceptions flow from the socket methods and wrap them in a higher layer. I have a connection abstraction that handles message framing and eventually keep alives.

Comment: Just should you not be aware, `NetworkStream` has [`ReadAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.readasync(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`WriteAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.writeasync(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

Comment: `Socket` implements `IDisposable` therefore your class should as well and properly implement the Disposable pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the suggestions! They helped me make some improvements and directed me towards a better design. I know this is a pretty simple piece of code but still. I moved the error handling and closed connection detection to a higher level connection abstraction. I also added an interface to make mocking and unit testing my message framing and keep alive messages easier. Final implementation below.

EDIT: Mocking this is a massive pain. Hrmm.

```
public interface ISimpleSocket : IDisposable
{
    void Bind(int port);
    void Listen(int backlog);
    Task<ISocket> AcceptAsync();
    Task ConnectAsync(string host, int port);
    Task<int> ReceiveAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);
    Task SendAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);
}

public class SimpleSocket : ISimpleSocket
{
    private readonly Socket _socket;

    private SimpleSocket(Socket socket)
    {
        _socket = socket;
    }

    public SimpleSocket()
    {
        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    public void Bind(int port)
    {
        var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
        _socket.Bind(endPoint);
    }

    public void Listen(int backlog)
    {
        _socket.Listen(backlog);
    }

    public async Task<ISimpleSocket> AcceptAsync()
    {
        var socket = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(_socket.BeginAccept, _socket.EndAccept, true);
        return new SimpleSocket(socket);
    }

    public async Task ConnectAsync(string host, int port)
    {
        await Task.Factory.FromAsync(_socket.BeginConnect, _socket.EndConnect, host, port, null);
    }

    public async Task<int> ReceiveAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        using (var stream = new NetworkStream(_socket))
        {
            return await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count);
        }
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        using (var stream = new NetworkStream(_socket))
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, offset, count);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _socket?.Dispose();
    }
}
```